# How to implement DLNA client using iOS9 or tvOS

Tags: ios, ios9, upnp, tvos, dlna

DLNA communicates using HTTP (correct?) which is now banned by Apple's new policy.

See: [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

You could set the settings in .plist file as advised above but that would require that you know all the hosts where the DLNA server listens to.
I also believe that you can not change the .plist on the fly.

Can you easily switch DLNA server to run on http**S**? Is this a "standard" feature?

What is your recommendation for this problem?

BTW, would you have a good tip for DLNA C++ client with reference implementation?

Comment: Use the second suggestion in the linked question `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`

Comment: Hm, that works but is not allowed (as written somewhere). It may be rejected by Apple...

Comment: Everything in this thread suggests it is fine. It is a documented key after all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534304/does-app-store-reject-submission-if-nsallowsarbitraryloads-set-to-yes

Comment: UPnP mandates use of plain HTTP.  DLNA can be thought of as providing a wrapper to UPnP so has no standard option to run over HTTPS.  [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/) docs suggest restrictions may only apply to certain objective C classes.  If this is correct, you could run a UPnP (or DLNA) control point by using BSD socket APIs rather than objective C.  There are plenty of standard C (or C++) UPnP libraries around if you don't fancy taking on the work for this yourself.

Comment: Thanks @simonc Why don't you write your comment as an answer? I'll happily accept it as correct answer. Would you recommend any specific UPnP libs?