# iOS 9 App Transport Security for multiple services

Tags: ios, ios9, app-transport-security

I am using **parse.com**, **layer.com**, and **my company url** for terms/privacy policy, as well as other frameworks in `cocoapods` like google places api.

I am stuck because I want to use the correct `Apple Transport Settings`, and I can't seem to figure out how to include all the things I need in the `info.plist`. ***I don't want it to get rejected from the app store on submission***.

I have done research on stack overflow and people either by passed it or gave an example for one domain. It still isn't clear how I should add this in the xml.

Comment: Better find an alternative for parse...

Comment: There are many examples for setting up ATS. Address each one of the domains separately. Keep in mind that you only need to add to ATS for a domain that isn't up-to-date already.

Comment: Linus G. Yes I know, will be doing their migration when more tools become available. And @rmaddy what do you mean "for a domain that isn't up-to-date already"

Comment: @kareem I mean that not all domains (such as parse.com, etc.) will require anything for ATS. You only need to setup ATS for a domain that doesn't use the proper version of HTTPS/TLS.

Comment: @rmaddy whats the best way to know if it doesnt use the proper HTTPS/TLS ?

Comment: You know if you can't access the server without an entry for ATS in Info.plist

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to add one domain to the exceptions dictionary, then you just do the same for all the others. Here's an example:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>parse.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>                
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>layer.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>my-company.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Also, the full spec for `NSAppTransportSecurity` keys can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33).

Answer (score 0):

don't worry about the reject things

according to [this guys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32837300/4730119)

> The good news is Apple Accepted my app with NSAllowsArbitraryLoads set
>   to YES.

So in your case the simplest way is to allow all http request in this way, and if your app have built-in web browser, this is definitely your choice

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
```

If you want to just allow specific http request, then you can add this in your info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

code above says allow `yourserver.com` and its subdomain http connection