# NSURL fails to load in web view -9824

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I am making an app that returns book reviews based on isbn. I am trying to load the Goodreads review widget in a web view but I am getting two errors:

`CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)` and `NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)`

I have tried several other urls and get the same result.

Here is my code where I am calling the url:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = NSURL (string: "https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#book.show_by_isbn");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj);
}
```

In the info.plist I have a `goodreads.com` dictionary within the Exception Domains dictionary. I included in goodreads.com `NSIncludesSubdomains, NSExceptionsAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads, and NSExceptionsMinimumTLSVersion` (set to TLSv1.1)

Is there something obvious that I am going wrong? Is the domain wrong?

---

**EDIT:** For anyone reading this later, I think I have solved it. This page ([Does App Store reject submission if NSAllowsArbitraryLoads set to YES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534304/does-app-store-reject-submission-if-nsallowsarbitraryloads-set-to-yes)) helped immensely.

The App Store will reject your app if you use `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`. However, they will allow `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent`

Per Apple developer guidelines,

> "Set this key’s value to YES to obtain exemption from ATS policies in
>   your app’s web views, without affecting the ATS-mandated security of
>   your NSURLSession connections. To support older versions of iOS and
>   macOS (older than iOS 10), you can employ this key and still manually configure ATS. To do
>   so, set this key’s value to YES and also configure the
>   NSAllowsArbitraryLoads subways. If you add this key to your Info.plist
>   file, then, irrespective of the value of the key, ATS ignores the
>   value of the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key."

Comment: Have you checked this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9

Comment: TLS 1.1 is too low.

Comment: I tried 1.2 and still received the same error.

Comment: @Natarajan I have read that post before, I did not find a satisfactory answer though. Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add NSAppTransportSecurity in your project.plist and check whether your url request is working or not.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have already researched this option. It correctly loads the url, but I have read NSAllowsArbitraryLoads is a hack that is not accepted by the App Store. I would like to eventually put this app on the store so I am looking for other options... Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow specific domain use it this way it is more secure than allowing all

```
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Fix is easy add the line below and it works.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I have attached the project I tested on

[LINK TO THE PROJECT](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2csGr9uKp1DdGZmanItNUhtRjQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: right, in the last part of my original post I explained that I have already entered this in my info.plist. I have goodreads.com in the place of yourserver.com. I still get these errors despite having this in my info.plist.

Comment: @OliviaMurphy can you upload your plist on dropbox and share the link?

Comment: here is a picture of the section of info.plist in question: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B813Fyr_yfVSUVhsVVlXX2hNOVU/view

Comment: @OliviaMurphy wait for a minute

Comment: @OliviaMurphy i need plist file not image

Comment: Note that the TLS version says 1.0, but I have also tried 1.1 and 1.2

Comment: @OliviaMurphy I fixed it

Comment: @OliviaMurphy i have attached the project just download and see it works. if it works well don't forget to accept and upvote the answer :)

Comment: I see you used NSAllowsArbitraryLoads, as the commenter below you suggested. From everything I've read though, this is a hack and is not allowed by the app store. I would like to put this app on the store.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to make sure that App Sandbox is disabled in Targets > Capabilities. Xcode automatically enables it for freshly generated projects.