# SFSafariViewControllers not working in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have some SFSafariViewControllers in my app. However, all of a sudden they're not working anymore. I present them with the following code:

```
SFSafariViewController *sfsvc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
[self presentViewController:sfsvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But the result I get, is this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: are you added the NSTransportsecurtiy in your app

Comment: You shouldn't need to add the NSTransportSecurity key in your plist if you're accessing secure sites. Does the console say anything?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31534304/does-app-store-reject-submission-if-nsallowsarbitraryloads-set-to-yes

Comment: I already have, by the way. For other purposes. But it's there.

Comment: Only thing the console says is: `Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged`. Hmm, that wasn't there before....

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890761/warning-presenting-view-controllers-on-detached-view-controllers-is-discourage

Comment: That's definitely not the problem. I fixed it and it's still doing it.

Comment: Your code works for me.